# Twilio Websockets: retrieve stream's payload only

Tags: websocket, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

According to this guide ( https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/consume-real-time-media-stream-using-websockets-python-and-flask ) you can consume a real-time Media Stream using WebSockets.

However, instead of creating a stream's fork like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://yourdomain.ngrok.io/media" />
     </Start>
     <Dial>+15550123456</Dial>
</Response>
```

how would you only receive the stream's payload via websocket without specifying `<Dial></Dial>` endpoint. If you remove `<Dial></Dial>` tag there, call ends as `<Stream />` is asynchronous and there is no following event to be handled.

Would you replace `<Dial></Dial>` with some other tag?